# Upload log4j2 JSON formatted log files to AWS CloudWatch with correct timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, log4j2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to upload log files to AWS CloudWatch. The application is outputting log4j2 style JSON into a file:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout

AWS provide 2 cloudwatch log agents for this task. An 'older' agent, and a 'unified' agent:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html

I have tried using both agents, but run into the following problems, mainly related to parsing timestamps and the fact that the agent is doing a regex match on the entire log line and is not parsing the it as JSON:

An example log message (additional fields omitted):

`{"message": "Processing data for previous day: 2019-06-17T02:01:00", "timestamp": "2019-06-18T17:16:19.338000+0100"}`

1. The older agent threw an exception because it was attempting to use my configured timestamp format to parse the timestamp in the message, not the one in the `timestamp` field.
2. The unified agent is unable to parse timestamps with sub-second precision which results in problems when attempting to combine log streams from multiple sources.

So, is there a better tool/strategy to upload JSON formatted log4j2 files to CoudWatch?

Comment: I haven't tried this, so not an answer, but I believe that if you just send the raw JSON to CloudWatch, _without parsing,_ you'll get the results you want. The timestamp on the log entry will be only approximate -- the time the agent picked up the message -- but you'd do analytics using the timestamp embedded in the message.

Comment: IMO a better solution, however, is to write directly to CloudWatch Logs. Since you're using Log4J 2.0, I won't make a shameless plug for [my appender library](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders), but if you Google for "log4j2 cloudwatch appender" you'll see several options (I can't speak to any of them).

Comment: No - the aws agent(s) support parsing the timestamp from the message, so that the timestamp is set correctly in cloudwatch. It just doesn't support parsing a timestamp with sub-millisecond precision (And the older one, which does support that, can be tripped up by other timestamps in the log lines). Thanks for the cloudwatch log4j2 appender - I have already looked at this but I don't really want to add the dependency to all of our services.

Comment: I took a look at this, and unless there's an undocumented configuration code, you don't get millis at all: `%S` translates to `\d{2}` in the imported config (the "toml" file). I should also note that the CloudWatch Logs API deals with timestamps as millis-since-epoch, so you may have issues with sub-milli timestamps even if they did parse.